# Simulating touch gestures on XNA in windows

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0

I am developing a game for Windows Phone 7 using XNA, and I have set it up so that it runs as a Windows XNA app as well. The thing that I am having a problem with now is simulating the XNA touch gestures using the mouse in the same way that the Windows Phone 7 emulator does. I can't use the Windows Phone 7 emulator because it refuses to run on my laptop, because the hardware isn't new enough.

Any ideas on where I might either find a library which can translate mouse data to touch gestures, or where I might find enough information to get started without huge amounts of guesswork?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good article about [Gestures](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/CSWP7GestureDetection-2aca7ef8) (CS)/[Gestures](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/VBWP7GestureDetection-a604bcde) (VB).

> Article Overview
>
> Compare the Gestures abilities of Windows Phone 7 to other major phone
>   platforms, and learn how to take both gesture and raw touch input on
>   Windows Phone 7. This article is a thorough comparison of the gestures
>   features available across the major phone platforms, and contains code
>   to support basic touch-based input scenarios.

Comment: I have accepted this one, although it didn't really answer my question directly. In the end I had to reverse engineer what was coming through when using the emulator...

Comment: Link is now dead. Any chance you could post your gesture code for Windows, Neil?